# Not all rows outputting PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

in this code I am trying to output all images with the tag I searched. I created 2 images with the same tag 'hi'.

The program is only outputting one of the images though. But when I echo the $rows number it equals 2. When I ran the query in MYSQL it also returned 2 rows. I do not see why ALL the images are being shown.

```
 $input = ($_GET['input']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$input%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$image = $data['image'];
     header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
     echo $image;
```

This isn't all my code but it is all that I think is necessary. Here is what is being shown in another page.

```
echo "<img src='photolarge.php?input=$input'>"
```

When I echo $rows it outputs the number 2 so I know the query is working.

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10+ times a day

Comment: I'm doing it for Buddha.

Comment: regardless of house many times its seen, it still needs to be said :/

Comment: Oh come on "don't use mysql_" doesn't need posting on every question that mentions it. Let's be realistic, until every copy of the php mysql extension is deleted from all servers in all of the world, it will still work. Obsessive is an understatement.

Comment: @popnoodles You're free to not encourage best practice.

Comment: Shame I'm not free to flag as annoying, pointless and nothing to do with actually answering the question.

Comment: It is annoying but as long as they also answer the question like he did its ok. I will get into the habbit another time :)

Comment: So he did. Some mitigation there!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a loop to iterate through the result array.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$input%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $rows[image];
}
```

As I mentioned in the comments, please don't use `mysql_` functions. You also need to sanitize your parameter as your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Ok well I know what you are doing but I am also re-sizing the image in the same file. so I tried `code`while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$image = $data['image']; `code`     And that still only would output 1 image

Comment: I need a variable so I can re-size it.

Comment: Ok I tried what you did and it still did not work  `ob_start();

$input = $_GET['input'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$input%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $rows['image'];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch all returned rows in line 4, not only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$input%'";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['image'];
   }
```

tips: try to change to `MYSQLI` or `PDO` ,MYSQL is no longer maintained